# AddItem in CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton - new value is not shown

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, future, pack

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

I have a problem with `AddItem` in `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton`.

I added `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton` to tool bar (I used this solutions: [click here](http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/1691981/)).

The problem is call `AddItem()` method in run time.

I checked in Quick Watch object which calls this method. In this object, the new value appears. But I don't see it in application.

What can be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Care to share the code you've actually tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is wrong method to use. The correct method is `ReplaceButton().`